# can't do copy using docker and getting error as directory not found?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, azure-functions, docker-build

When I'm trying to install packages using docker 
I'm getting the following error

```
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/overlay2/7f434dda3e872abd56226080297095cbc3ebd1decef703550c2c12fead4a6e94/merged/home/site/wwwroot: no such file or directory
```

here is my dockerfile

```
COPY . /home/site/wwwroot


FROM ubuntu
# ...
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get -y install gcc mono-mcs && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY --from=0 /home/site/wwwroot /home/site/wwwroot
RUN cd /home/site/wwwroot && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

how to resolve it?

Comment: `WORKDIR` may helps?

Comment: can you help me with how to add it?

Answer (score -1):

You can also try : Just make sure your pip path is correct, do `which pip` to make sure what the pip path is.
Then put this in your docker file instead of the last line:

```
...

RUN /usr/bin/pip -r /home/site/wwwroot/requirements.txt
```

Let me know if you don't understand my answer.

Comment: how do I find the path of pip

Comment: It looked like your were trying to copy your code and requirements.txt over. I forgot to mention that this line: ```COPY --from=0 /home/site/wwwroot /home/site/wwwroot``` is incorrect. You can't copy from something to itself, but what you can try instead is to copy all the source code into your container with ```COPY . /home/site/wwwroot``` Check this link: https://qxf2.com/blog/how-to-get-the-code-inside-docker-container/